# How to add interpolation string to before jQuery function

Tags: javascript

I have a variable

```
selectedRowData.text = 'xyz';
```

This text, I need to append to the title like below.

```
 elem.find('#cv-k-grid-td-alert .k-grid-alert').before('<span class="k-icon k-i-paste-plain-text notes-icon" title=`${selectedRowData.text}`></span>');
```

This title is coming as `${selectedRowData.text}` in browser
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: is this an angular or angularjs question? You have tagged both, but you need to decide which framework you are actually working with ;) If you are using angular, instead explain what you are tryíng to achieve, because there is probably an angular way to solve this, instead of using jquery, which doesn't work so well with angular.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with angular or jquery - its a javascript question about how to use interpolated strings.

Answer (score 0):

The whole string needs to be interpolated not just that little part

```
elem.find('#cv-k-grid-td-alert .k-grid-alert')
    .before(`<span class="k-icon k-i-paste-plain-text notes-icon" title="${selectedRowData.text}"></span>`);
```